# Installing plyvel with pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, leveldb

I am getting this error when trying to install plyvel :

```
  Running setup.py install for plyvel
    Complete output from command /home/eytan/.virtualenvs/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NVZgbQ/plyvel/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jHZNqS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/eytan/.virtualenvs/env/include/site/python2.7/plyvel:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/plyvel
    copying plyvel/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/plyvel
    copying plyvel/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/plyvel
    running build_ext
    building 'plyvel._plyvel' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/plyvel
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:359:24: fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory
     #include "leveldb/db.h"
                            ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/eytan/.virtualenvs/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NVZgbQ/plyvel/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jHZNqS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/eytan/.virtualenvs/env/include/site/python2.7/plyvel" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NVZgbQ/plyvel
```

Can someone explain what's going on and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the leveldb development package.

On deb based distributions:

```
sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev
```

On RPM based distributions:

```
sudo yum install leveldb-devel
```

Note that `dnf` is slowly but surely replacing `yum`. If your distribution uses `dnf` (e.g., Fedora 23 and newer), you can just drop it in there instead of `yum`:

```
sudo dnf install leveldb-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev
```

and then try again to run pip install.

More info: [source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/_nqvaNZk2Bw)

Answer (score 0):

For centos 6.X

```
yum install epel-release
yum install leveldb-devel
```